# Multiple inheritance and using a method of one of the base classes

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "A"
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def Update(self):
        print "Update A"
        self.PickTarget()

    def PickTarget(self):
        print "PickTarget A"

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "B"
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def Update(self):
        print "Update B"
        self.PickTarget()

    def PickTarget(self):
        print "PickTarget B"

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()

    def Update(self, useA):
        if useA:
            A.Update(self)
        else:
            B.Update(self)

c = C()

c.Update(useA = True)
# prints: 
# Update A
# PickTarget A

c.Update(useA = False)
# prints:
# Update B
# PickTarget A
```

Why does calling `C.Update` with `useA=False` still call into `A.PickTarget`? How can I make this work how I want it to work (ie B.Update always calls into B.PickTarget)? I'm sure this has been asked before but my searching turned up nothing - probably because I don't know what to search for.

Comment: Though I still think this may call for a redesign, I'll point out that  name mangling offers a fairly flexible solution to this problem. See [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849519/multiple-inheritance-and-using-a-method-of-one-of-the-base-classes/6849613#6849613).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `A` is before `B` in `C`'s base classes.

You need to use `B.PickTarget(self)` rather than `self.PickTarget()` in `B.Update(self)` to get this behavior. Otherwise, switch `A` and `B` in `C`'s definition.

Edit:

If the intended behavior is for `B` to always call methods in `B` and for `A` to always call methods in `A`, it's **correct** to use `A.method(self)` instead of `self.method()`, as the second form doesn't imply that `method` is in `A`.

You should redesign your classes. `A` should have a move method that moves the robot randomly and define it's other basic behavior. `B` should be a subclass of `A` and should have a move method that calls `super(B, self).move()` if it doesn't have a path, and otherwise moves on the path. This is the proper way to override a method on a condition.

Comment: Is there no way that this can be done without modifying A and B? This is just example code - in the real code, A and B are used stand-alone, too. (The actual code is some simple AI for robots - A makes the bot move randomly, B makes the bot follow a path, C checks if the bot has a path - if not, it calls A.Update, if so, it calls B.Update. If there are better ways to deal with this, I'm all ears.)

Comment: Like I said, you can just switch `A` and `B` in `C`'s definition. Also, it sounds like your intended behavior is for `B` to always call methods in `B` and for `A` to always call methods in `A` in which case it's __correct__ to use `A.method(self)` instead of `self.method()`, as the second form doesn't imply that `method` is in `A`.

Comment: I see! Now this is starting to make sense. How does this work for accessing attributes in the class? For example, accessing self.name inside A.Update - should it be self.name or A.name?

Comment: `self.name`. You're still passing `self` to `Update`, and `name` is an instance variable so it's on `self` not `A`. See my edit though, you're better off redesigning your classes.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever a method of an object is called, python uses the "Method Resolution Order" (MRO) to determine which version of the method to call. In this case, although you have explicitly called `A.Update()`, `A.Update()` doesn't explicitly call `A.PickTarget`. It just calls `self.PickTarget()`. Since this is a `C` object, that's equivalent to `C.PickTarget(self)`. `C.PickTarget()` is inherited, and the `C` MRO dictates in this case that `A.PickTarget` is the version of `PickTarget` to use.

You can look at the MRO of `C` like this:

```
>>> C.__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class 'foo.A'>, <class 'foo.B'>, <type 'object'>)
```

There's a super-informative article on the MRO [here](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

---

Regarding how to get the behavior you want -- well, there are lots of pretty obvious ways, and at the same time, no *good* ones (that I can think of). I don't think this is really a good design. The main point of multiple inheritance is that you can mix and match orthogonal methods in `C`, but you're trying to cram multiple versions of roughly similar methods, two from `A` and two from `B`, into one class. If you tell us more about what you're doing, maybe we can suggest a better solution. (You're also changing the signature of your method while keeping the same name. That seems dodgy to me as well.)

If you're sure that you want to do this, though, another approach you might consider is [name mangling](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables), which is designed exactly for cases like this. This does exactly what you want:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "A"
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def Update(self):
        print "Update A"
        self.__PickTarget()

    def PickTarget(self):
        print "PickTarget A"

    __PickTarget = PickTarget

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "B"
        super(B, self).__init__()

    def Update(self):
        print "Update B"
        self.__PickTarget()

    def PickTarget(self):
        print "PickTarget B"

    __PickTarget = PickTarget

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()

    def Update(self, useA):
        if useA:
            A.Update(self)
        else:
            B.Update(self)
```

Output:

```
>>> from mangling import A, B, C
>>> c = C()
>>> c.Update(useA = True)
Update A
PickTarget A
>>> c.Update(useA = False)
Update B
PickTarget B
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to why this happens. I have tried setting self.PickTarget in C.Update() to either A.PickTarget or B.PickTarget, but this throws "TypeError: unbound method PickTarget() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)"

Comment: @combatdave, I don't quite understand what you mean by "setting self.PickTarget in C.Update() to either A.PickTarget or B.PickTarget". Do you mean you're doing `self.PickTarget = A.PickTarget`? Because that's super wrong. `A.PickTarget` is an unbound method, so now it's not bound to `self` anymore, and you have to pass `self` explicitly.

Comment: Yep, I did mean that - I figured it was wrong ;) Thanks for the post - this helped me understand what is going on, but the post by @agf fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the solution but if you change **C's** update method to:

```
def update(self, useA):
    if useA:
        A().update()
    else:
        B().update()
```

It does work as you expected to.

You should read about Python's Method Resolution Order in order to work with things like this properly.

Comment: That's creating a new instance of the base class to call Update() on, which isn't useful.

Comment: Then try switch A for B in C's definition.
EDIT: Also, if you try printing C.name, you'd see what is happening.