# Inherit same function name from several classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I was reading on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849519/multiple-inheritance-and-using-a-method-of-one-of-the-base-classes) thread on stackoverflow but it looked like the solution was wrong according to a user and most important, it couldnt solve my question and I dont know if its because the answer is in python 2 or whatnow.

However, lets say i have this code

```
class A:
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hi")

class B:
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hello")

class C(A, B):
    def say_hello(self):
        super().say_hello()
        print("Hey")

welcome = C()
welcome.say_hello()
```

How can i call both class A and B from class C without changing the names of the functions?
As i read in the other thread you could do something like `super(B, self).say_hello()` but that does not seem to work, I dont know why though.

Comment: What do you mean by "Does not seem to work"? Are you getting any sort of error message? Erroneous output?

Comment: To elaborate on Davy's comment, what output did you *expect*? What output are you getting? Your question "How can i call both class A and B from class C" is not clear - but I think you just want `A.say_hello(self)` then `B.say_hello(self)`. `super` will use the next-class in the MRO. If you don't want to enumerate the actual values, then you are going to have to give more details...

Comment: Your call to `super` invokes `A.say_hello`, but that method doesn't call `super`, so the chain of calls ends.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use `super` properly, *every* class involved needs to be designed correctly. Among other things:

1. *One* class should be the "root" for the method, meaning it will not use `super` to delegate calls further. This class must appear after any other class providing the method.
2. All classes that are not the root must use `super` to pass call the method from any other class that might define the method.

---

```
# Designated root class for say_hello
class A:
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hi")

# Does not inherit say_hello, but must be aware that it is not the root
# class, and it should delegate a call further up the MRO
class B:
    def say_hello(self):
        super().say_hello()
        print("Hello")

# Make sure A is the last class in the MRO to ensure all say_hello
# methods are called.
class C(B, A):
    def say_hello(self):
        super().say_hello()
        print("Hey")

welcome = C()
welcome.say_hello()
```

Here, `super` in `C.say_hello` will call `B.say_hello`, whose `super` will call `A.say_hello`.

---

If you don't want go along with the requirements for using `super`, just call the other class's methods explicitly. There is no *requirement* to use `super`.

```
class A:
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hi")

class B:
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hello")

class C(A, B):
    def say_hello(self):
        A.say_hello(self)
        B.say_hello(self)
        print("Hey")
```

Comment: does the order of the superclasses matter in your definition of `C`?

Comment: Yes; if A comes before B, then `A.say_hello` will always be called before `B.say_hello`, which will prevent `B.say_hello` from being called at all.

Comment: Very interesting, I had no idea about that the order of calling mattered:
So if you did as i do by calling class(A,B) it did not work, but if you do it by B,A it works.

Thanks for helping out and explaining

Comment: @chepner in your solution, who is the parent of B? when you use super().say_hello() inside B, to which parent's method are you calling?

Comment: The parent of `B` is `object`, but in `B.sayhello`, you don't *know* which class `super` will access next; that depends entirely on the runtime type of `self`, whose method-resolution order (MRO) is used to decide which class comes after `B`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to decide which class (A or B) is the designated root class, you can also implement an abstract superclass for both A and B.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class ISayHello(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def say_hello(self):
        pass
 
class A(ISayHello):
    def say_hello(self):
        super().say_hello()
        print("Hi")


class B(ISayHello):
    def say_hello(self):
        super().say_hello()
        print("Hello")
 
 
class C(B,A):
    def say_hello(self):
        super().say_hello()
        print("Hey")

welcome_c = C() 
welcome_c.say_hello()
```

This would make sense if you have an additional class D with different root class than C.

```py
class D(A,B):
    def say_hello(self):
        super().say_hello()
        print("Hey")

welcome_d = D() 
welcome_d.say_hello()
```